# Dockerized Nginx, Domain not working properly

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I managed to dockerized my django app. With docker-compose I can run django,postgresql and nginx but Nginx not working well. I can access my app and it works fine but when I tried to connect to my domain, always work at port 8000. I want to run my app at testapp.org but I can only access wtih testapp.org. How can I solve this? What changed do I need to use in my configuration file? Did I missed something?

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db.postgres
    image: postgres:10
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=testdb
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    image: djangoapp
    command: bash -c "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && gunicorn fatihkocnet.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./fatihkocnet:/fatihkocnet
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    expose:
      - "8000"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./fatihkocnet:/fatihkocnet
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
```

nginx/test.conf

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {
  location / {
  proxy_pass http://web;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_redirect off;
    }
  listen 8000;
  server_name testapp.org;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map Docker Hosts port (80 if you want to host service on HTTP port) to your ngnix docker service.

e.g.
      ports:
      - "80:8000"

You need to map your HOST servers IP into DNS to your testapp.org address.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now my website running with single command. Changing ports figured my problem.

Comment: Great to read that.  As I can see you are new contributor on stack overflow, whenever you get help by the answers on questions think of "Upvoting" the answer. You can "upvote" questions too if you find them useful to your life. That's how communities run ;)

Comment: I am doing that bu system don't show yet. Because I am really new :D